# gulp.src is not writing destination files out

Tags: sass, gulp, angular5, gulp-sass

This is pretty weird. I have this output:

```
converting sass to css...
[18:36:00] gulp-debug: src/app/app.component.scss
[18:36:00] gulp-debug: src/app/pages/about/about.component.scss
[18:36:00] gulp-debug: src/app/pages/contact/contact.component.scss
[18:36:00] gulp-debug: src/app/pages/home/home.component.scss
[18:36:00] gulp-debug: src/app/pages/home/components/control-panel/control-panel.component.scss
[18:36:00] gulp-debug: 5 items
notify clients of css change
change /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/app/app.component.css
change /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/app/pages/home/home.component.css
change /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/app/pages/home/components/control-panel/control-panel.component.css
change /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/app/pages/about/about.component.css
change /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/app/pages/contact/contact.component.css
```

here is my code:

```
  const gulp = require('gulp');
  const gdebug = require('gulp-debug');
  const sass = require('gulp-sass');

  console.log('converting sass to css...');
  gulp.src(path.resolve(root + '/src/**/**/*.scss'))
    .pipe(gdebug())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
    .once('finish', function () {
      console.log('notify clients of css change');
      notifyClients();
    });
```

From the logs it looks like the files are being written out, but from my editor, there don't appear to be any new .css files in the filesystem, only .scss files. Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: I added the `gdebug()` call, but the same thing was happening without it, so that is not causing the problem tmk

Comment: Is there a task associated with this? I've never seen a gulp command run without being within a gulp.task.

Comment: No task associated, just running the gulp code standalone

Answer (score 0):

Simply in case of dynamic src and you want respective same dest (as received in src) then you can use following

Example Suppose we have array of scss file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var scssArr = [
    'src/asdf/test2.scss',
    'src/qwerty/test1.scss'
];

    
function runSASS(cb) {
    scssArr.forEach(function(p){
        gulp.src(p, {base:'.'})
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))//outputStyle is optional or simply sass()
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.')); //if othe folder including src path then use '/folder-name' instead of '.', so output path '/folder-name/{src-received-path}'
    })
    cb();
}

exports.runSASS = runSASS; // gulp runSASS
```

Run command `gulp runSASS` This will create following files:

> src/asdf/test2.css
>
> src/qwerty/test1.css

*Happy Coding..*